# Laplace transform by definition.

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I have to find the Laplace transform by definition of 
$ f(t) = \begin{cases} t^{2}, & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\ (t-1)^{-1}, & 1<t\leq 2 \\ 1, & 2<t\leq 3 \end{cases} $ 
But my doubt is in the interval $(3,\infty)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your function is not defined on $(3, \infty)$, so I'm guessing that it means that it's zero there.

Comment: @BenjaminWang if f is equal to zero in (3,∞) means that the function is defined, but it is not true.

Comment: Alright. Laplace transform is technically only defined for functions with domain including $[0, \infty)$, so in that case, you can say that the Laplace transform you want is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. @BenjaminWang